# Failure sending broadcast Intent SIM_STATE_CHANGED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to check the Sim card State and do several actions depending on its state.
From what i understood about the BroadcastReceiver, when the Sim State is changed, the onReceive method of the broadcastReceiver is executed.

Here's the BroadcastReceiver class :

```
public class SimStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
public SimStateListener() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.

    // Checks Sim card State
    TelephonyManager telephoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int simState = telephoneMgr.getSimState();

    switch (simState) {
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
            Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State absent");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
            Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State network locked");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
            Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State pin required");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
            Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State puk required");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
            Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State unknown");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
            Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State ready");
            String phoneNumber = telephoneMgr.getLine1Number();
            Log.i("SimStateListener", phoneNumber);
            Toast.makeText(context, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(phoneNumber.equals(myPhoneNumber)){
                // do nothing
                break;
            }
            else{
                Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim card is changed");
                // do something
                break;
            }
    }
}

}
```

Here is what i put in the Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<receiver android:name="com.example.trackyourandroid.SimStateListener" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Here is what i'm getting in the LogCat :

```
12-18 08:08:29.420: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-18 08:08:29.560: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-18 08:08:29.710: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-18 08:08:33.940: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-18 08:08:33.980: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-18 08:08:34.000: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-18 08:08:35.680: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-18 08:08:35.850: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-18 08:08:35.860: W/BroadcastQueue(1303): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
```

Stack trace :

```
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170): ANR in com.android.systemui
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170): PID: 2221
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170): Load: 6.4 / 2.12 / 1.02
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170): CPU usage from 3482ms to -8134ms ago:
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   38% 2170/system_server: 25% user + 13% kernel / faults: 1455 minor 10 major
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   15% 2330/com.android.launcher: 12% user + 3.3% kernel / faults: 2121 minor 10 major
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   14% 2151/surfaceflinger: 6.2% user + 8% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   13% 2319/com.android.phone: 8.9% user + 4.8% kernel / faults: 831 minor 3 major
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   6.6% 2221/com.android.systemui: 4.3% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 639 minor 6 major
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   2.8% 2161/bootanimation: 0.9% user + 1.9% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   1.2% 25/mtdblock0: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   1.5% 59/adbd: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   1% 12/kswapd0: 0% user + 1% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0.7% 2300/com.android.settings: 0.5% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 345 minor 1 major
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0.7% 2367/android.process.acore: 0.4% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 80 minor 1 major
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0.3% 48/rild: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 16 minor
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0.5% 2347/com.android.printspooler: 0% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 104 minor
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0.3% 284/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0.3% 1502/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0.2% 1//init: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0.1% 26/mtdblock1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   0% 43/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170): 100% TOTAL: 61% user + 38% kernel + 0% softirq
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170): CPU usage from 6733ms to 7312ms later:
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   31% 2170/system_server: 16% user + 15% kernel / faults: 65 minor
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     11% 2185/ActivityManager: 3.7% user + 7.5% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     6.3% 2181/Binder_1: 5% user + 1.2% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     3.7% 2182/Binder_2: 2.5% user + 1.2% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     2.5% 2177/Compiler: 1.2% user + 1.2% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     2.5% 2345/Binder_5: 1.2% user + 1.2% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     2.5% 2346/Binder_6: 0% user + 2.5% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     2.5% 2362/Binder_8: 1.2% user + 1.2% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     1.2% 2251/Binder_3: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   15% 2319/com.android.phone: 11% user + 3.6% kernel / faults: 51 minor
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     8% 2319/m.android.phone: 5.8% user + 2.2% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     2.9% 2326/Compiler: 2.2% user + 0.7% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     2.9% 2381/RILReceiver: 2.9% user + 0% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     1.4% 2380/RILSender: 0.7% user + 0.7% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   13% 2330/com.android.launcher: 8.4% user + 4.9% kernel / faults: 567 minor 8 major
12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     11% 2330/ndroid.launcher: 7.7% user + 3.5% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     1.4% 2334/GC: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     0.7% 2339/Compiler: 0.7% user + 0% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   10% 2221/com.android.systemui: 9.1% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 112 minor
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     9.8% 2221/ndroid.systemui: 7.7% user + 2.1% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     0.7% 2228/Compiler: 0.7% user + 0% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   2.8% 2151/surfaceflinger: 0.7% user + 2.1% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     1.4% 2156/DispSync: 0.7% user + 0.7% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     0.7% 2151/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     0.7% 2166/Binder_4: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   1.3% 48/rild: 0.6% user + 0.6% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     1.3% 76/rild: 0.6% user + 0.6% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   1.7% 12/kswapd0: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):   1.5% 59/adbd: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170):     1.5% 279/adbd: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
    12-18 10:53:18.850: E/ActivityManager(2170): 100% TOTAL: 62% user + 37% kernel
    12-18 10:53:21.560: E/InputDispatcher(2170): channel 'b3fdc490 StatusBar (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    12-18 10:53:21.570: E/InputDispatcher(2170): channel 'b40044f8 Keyguard (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    12-18 10:53:23.030: E/gralloc_goldfish(2151): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 480 x 800, usage b33
    12-18 10:53:23.080: E/(2151): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=480, h=800) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
    12-18 10:53:23.140: E/BufferQueue(2151): [ScreenshotSurface] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
    12-18 10:53:28.070: E/SoundPool(2424): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
    12-18 10:53:28.110: E/SoundPool(2424): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
    12-18 10:53:29.420: E/BluetoothAdapter(2300): Bluetooth binder is null
    12-18 10:53:35.860: E/NetdConnector(2170): NDC Command {12 bandwidth setiquota eth0 9223372036854775807} took too long (2654ms)
    12-18 10:53:39.770: E/BluetoothAdapter(2424): Bluetooth binder is null
    12-18 10:53:39.770: E/BluetoothAdapter(2424): Bluetooth binder is null
    12-18 10:53:39.960: E/BluetoothAdapter(2424): Bluetooth binder is null
    12-18 10:53:40.680: E/BluetoothAdapter(2424): Bluetooth binder is null
    12-18 10:53:42.740: E/BluetoothAdapter(2424): Bluetooth binder is null
    12-18 10:53:43.040: E/ConnectivityService(2170): startUsingNetworkFeature took too long: 8936ms
    12-18 10:53:44.840: E/logwrapper(2487): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
    12-18 10:53:45.260: E/NetdConnector(2170): NDC Command {18 interface fwmark exempt add 10.0.2.2/32} took too long (837ms)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1362)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:410)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     at android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy.performReceive(IIntentReceiver.java:124)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.scheduleRegisteredReceiver(ActivityThread.java:823)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:394)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
    12-18 10:53:45.360: E/JavaBinder(2424):     ... 1 more
```

I can't print anything in the LogCat, and i dont see any Toast appearing.

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace from your error log

Comment: @Submersed Please check the edited question. I'm not sure if that what you asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intent-filter is wrong, try to use this one instead:

```
<intent-filter>             
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I can't find SIM_STATE_CHANGED in the Code Completion. Do have any idea why it's not showing? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't appear on Code Completion... but does it work after the change?

Answer (score 0):

Problem due to the android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED intent has been reported by many people. One round about i could suggest is ..

Try using "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" intent. when this intent get broadcast. there you can check for current sim number and previously saved number.

Save the old number and check with the new number. This would serve the purpose.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but some phones does not require a reboot when changing the sim card. If i couldn't find an answer, i'll try the BOOT_COMPLETED. Thank you.